# Unable to dual boot in dell xps 14 with windows 8/8.1

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, wubi, dell

Hi  can anyone help me in dual booting the windows 8/8.1 to ubuntu 12.4/13 
when I am using the wubi file and I installed the ubuntu and It reboots and finally it showing me an error of 0xc000000f when I am searching for this error.I found that the drives must be in basic and I converted my drives to BasicBut still I cant instal can anyone suggest me an Idea to dual boot

Answer (score 0):

I also have same problem with my HP envy.i founded some way to do that.but it didn't work with me.but try it.

1.use earlier version (i used 12.04)

2.use 32 bit version of ISO

3.format USB in NTFS

4.disable fast-startup

5.Enable legacy boot on BIOS(don't know whether it has in dell)